# Solve the homogeneous differential equation with functional coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this equation:
$$ y''-\frac{1}{x} y' + \frac{1}{x^3} y =0 $$

This is a nonconstant coefficient homogeneous differential equation.

How should I do it?

I tried with the supstitution: $y(x)=u(x)\sqrt{x}$, and then I got this equation:
$$u''+(\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{3}{4x^2})u=0$$, which seems to me easier to solve, but I don't know how to solve this either!

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a simple solution exists? [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+-+y%27%2Fx+%2B+y%2Fx%5E3+%3D+0) only finds a solution using Bessel functions. Now, WA is not always simplifying perfectly, so it's possible the solution is simpler than what it says.

Comment: The solution containes the Bessel-function:$$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,x{{ J}_{2}\left(2\,{\frac {1}{
\sqrt {x}}}\right)}+{\it \_C2}\,x{{ Y}_{2}\left(2\,{\frac {1}{
\sqrt {x}}}\right)}$$